# SQL Graph Database VS Cosmos Gremlin graph DB

Tags: graph, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, sql-graph

I have been thinking about what are the pros and cons of SQL Graph Database and Cosmos Graph Database, as far as I understand, SQL graph database is using nodes and vertex, but it still stores all of the information in tables.

So my question would be if the graph data can be handled by graph Db, what are the advantages of using SQL graph database? What is the added value of it compared with the original graph Database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Graph Database and Cosmos Graph Database both are almost same kind of services, just the structure of handling the data is different. As such there are no advantages and disadvantages, but choosing the right service based on your use-case is the key factor.

> Azure Cosmos DB's Gremlin API combines the power of graph database
> algorithms with highly scalable, managed infrastructure to provide a
> unique, flexible solution to most common data problems associated with
> lack of flexibility and relational approaches.

So, by using Azure Cosmos DB Gremlin API, you will get more leverage on the datasets with additional features. On the top of that, all the prerequisites will be taken care by CosmosDB while creating the database using Gremlin API.

In SQL Graph DB, nodes and edges are in tabular form, whereas in Cosmos DB it is in JSON like format.

I would highly encourage you to analyze how these databases support graph database models and the mechanism to exploit the maximum potential of these database systems for the right use-cases.

Please refer below articles to get the better understanding of both the services.

[SQL Graph Architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-architecture?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=SQL%20Graph%20Database,-Users%20can%20create&text=A%20graph%20is%20a%20collection,nodes%20belonging%20to%20a%20graph.)

[Introduction to Gremlin API in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph/graph-introduction)

Comment: We set up graph DB for storing the RDF sets. The scenario is we want to be able to edit the data and node in a very flexible way. Meanwhile, User Management is also required. I looked into lots documents, still can't decide what is better in our case

Comment: for RDF, CosmosDB Gremlin API is the better option. You won't need to manage the configurations like scalability, indexing, etc.

Comment: Good point! Thanks for sharing your opinion.